GCP Workflows Failing with "Parallel threads memory limit exceeded" Error
I have a process that can kick off up to 11 workflows at the same time. Last night, 5 of these were kicked off at the same time, and all five failed with the following error:
    Parallel threads memory limit exceeded
in step "UNKNOWN"
{
  "message": "Parallel threads memory limit exceeded",
  "tags": [
    "MemoryLimitExceededError"
  ]
}

I assume there is a memory or parallelization quota somewhere that we are hitting, but I can't find any documentation on this error specifically.
The step of the workflow that fails starts a dataflow job, then wait for it to finish by querying the status of the dataflow job every minute. This should not get close to any API quotas that I have been able to find.
Does anyone know where this error comes from?

Im hitting the same error since a couple of days without making any changes.

Hi @Ben, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCPsupport case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker  describing your issue.

I've created an interenal google support case & a public issue.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/363544353
Please leave a comment on the public issue if you have any additional information on the error.
